# Creating a Reusable Column Type Annotation for JPA to Set Size and Nullability

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-annotations

I'm working with several tables that have multiple fields sharing common characteristics, such as attributes like length and nullability. For instance, the field `Username` remains consistent across various tables.

Is it possible to create a custom annotation that automatically sets the size and nullability of these fields? For instance, an annotation like `@DescriptionColumn` could imply a default length of 255 characters and a non-nullable constraint.

In T-SQL, I would typically create a custom SQL type and apply it to all relevant fields. However, it seems that JPA doesn't directly support custom SQL types. Therefore, I'm exploring the idea of creating a reusable column type annotation to address this requirement.

Has anyone successfully implemented a similar solution or can provide guidance on creating such a custom annotation in JPA? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about custom annotation, but I can offer an example with [@CompositeType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddable-mapping-custom):

```
@CompositeType(StringCompositeUserType.class)
String userName;
```

and type definition:

```
public class StringCompositeUserType implements CompositeUserType<String> {
    public static class StringMapper {
        @Column(name = "user_name", length = 120, nullable = false)
        String name = "";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> embeddable() {
        return StringMapper.java;
    }

    ...
}
```